# Synchronized block throwing DuplicateKeyException

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, executor

Below is my class which is under threaded spring executors. Based on the type of source/service TAXP, TAXS, TAXT methods are getting called.
Logic is if the 'taxInfo.getGroupingId()' is already present in primary tax table do not insert, else insert primary table.
All secondary and tertiary tables records are inserted. TAXP, TAXS, TAXT are the topics and they receive data anytime. there might be milllisecond gap or at the same time the data would be sent so the blocks are synchroized.

All the 3 methods are called from 3 different thread executors.

```
executor1.insertPrimaryTaxInfo(taxInfo);
executor2.insertSecTaxInfo(taxInfo);
executor3.insertTerTaxInfo(taxInfo);

@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class TaxServiceImpl implements TaxService {
private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(ScanServiceImpl.class);
// TAXP
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = TaxServiceException.class)
    public void insertPrimaryTaxInfo(TaxInfo taxInfo) throws TaxServiceException {
        String taxId = null;
        try {

            synchronized (this) {
                taxId = taxMapper.checkExists(taxInfo.getGroupingId());             
                if (taxId == null) {
                    taxMapper.insertTaxInfo(taxInfo);   // primary tax table
                }
            }

            LOG.info("tax id --  " + taxId);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Error inserting txId for " + taxInfo.getGroupingId()
                    + ex);
            throw new TaxServiceException(ex);
        }
    }


// TAXS
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = TaxServiceException.class)
    public void insertSecTaxInfo(TaxInfo taxInfo) throws TaxServiceException {
        String taxId = null;
        try {

            synchronized (this) {
                taxId = taxMapper.checkExists(taxInfo.getGroupingId());             
                if (taxId == null) {
                    taxMapper.insertTaxInfo(taxInfo);   // primary tax table
                }
            }
            taxMapper.insertIntoSecTable(taxInfo); // secondary tax table
            LOG.info("tax id --  " + taxId);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Error inserting txId for " + taxInfo.getGroupingId()
                    + ex);
            throw new TaxServiceException(ex);
        }
    }


// TAXT
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = TaxServiceException.class)
    public void insertTerTaxInfo(TaxInfo taxInfo) throws TaxServiceException {
        String taxId = null;
        try {

            synchronized (this) {
                taxId = taxMapper.checkExists(taxInfo.getGroupingId());             
                if (taxId == null) {
                    taxMapper.insertTaxInfo(taxInfo);   // primary tax table
                }
            }
            taxMapper.insertIntoSecTable(taxInfo);  // secondary tax table
            taxMapper.insertIntoTerTable(taxInfo);  // Tertiary tax table
            LOG.info("tax id --  " + taxId);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Error inserting txId for " + taxInfo.getGroupingId()
                    + ex);
            throw new TaxServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

The issue is when TAXP, TAXS, TAXT are getting data at the same time, and the 3 above methods are called simultaneously. At a millisecond difference one of the thread inserts into primary table and the other thread trying to do the same but finds a record already exisitng in the table and throws duplicate key excepiton.

Im getting the below exception:

```
"com.data.exception.TaxServiceException: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TAXDB2.TAX_PK) violated
```

The reason for synchrnozing the block is to overcome this exception. What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: not entirely sure I follow you here, but you only synchronize some part of the method, it's not like an entire transaction waits for the other one to finish; as soon as you leave your synchronized block that thread is free to do whatever the JVM permits it - execute further, potential switch context (move to a different CPU), etc. It does not mean that it will simply run to completion, it still can happen that multiple threads reach the database with data ready to insert *at the same time*

Comment: but it sure looks like your default isolation level is `read uncommitted` here too... I might have to read your question again with a fresh mind in the morning

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be attempting to generate non guid based primary keys in your application instead of letting the database generate them and running into conflicts.

Its a losing battle to attempt to synchronize database access in your application. You should be letting the database manage the concurrency through its existing mechanisms. For more information refer to [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)). Additionaly, it is very instructive to lookup the current Isolation level on your database implementation and what it does in comparison to the others. For example SQL Server docs [Understanding Isolation Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: PrimaryKey would be the groupingId coming from the service. This is set that way so the same Goruping Id when coming form multiple services are handled correctly.